# Конвертация строки в коды символов Unicode

Tags: java, android, кодировка, unicode

Имею приложение. 2 EditText, один - поле ввода текста в utf,
второй - вывод преобразованного текста в формате `\uXXXX\uXXXX\uXXXX`
Я ввожу: `"Привет"`, а в ответ должен получить `"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"`

Нашел в интернете вот такой код, но у меня не заработало:

```
String ucs = ed_utf.getText().toString(); //получаю входные данные
try {
    byte[] utf8 = ucs.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String unicodeData = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
    ed_unicode.setText(unicodeData); //передаю строку в EditText2
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Выводится то же самое, что в входном EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
private static String getUnicodeCodes(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        result.append("\\u" + Integer.toHexString(str.charAt(i) | 0x10000).substring(1));

    return result.toString();
}
```

Решение позаимствованно [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character)

Comment: Спасибо! Немного изменил под себя, и заработало.